# Cheesecake Cooking Time Change with Pan Change?

Tags: cooking-time, cheesecake

I've made many cheesecakes before using a 9" spring-form in a water bath, and have always loved the result.  For a party coming up, I'd like to make individual-sized cheesecakes using a muffin/cupcake pan (Including liners).  So the question I have is what do I do to the cooking time?

All the recipes I've found for muffin-pan cheesecake say about 30 minutes (for example: [Cupid's Cherry Cheesecakes](http://www.kraftrecipes.com/recipes/cupids-cherry-cheesecakes-55259.aspx)).  But the recipe I plan on making (a modification of [White-Chocolate Raspberry Cheesecake](http://allrecipes.com//Recipe/white-chocolate-raspberry-cheesecake/Detail.aspx)) has a cook time of 55 minutes (in a normal spring-form).

So, what I was thinking is to only bake for 30 minutes.  I don't want to open the oven too often to check (and risk cold-shocking the cakes), so I'd prefer to get some insight.  I'm also planning on doing a water-bath below the muffin pan.

What do you think?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 30 minute cooking time is somewhat similar to my experience with mini-cheesecakes in a muffin tin, although I would recommend checking between 20 and 25 minutes with a toothpick.  In my experience mini-cheesecakes were cooked until set entirely in the middle, but if your recipe is for an NY-style cheesecake that seems to wobble a bit, things might be different.

Comment: Just for the record, it took the full 55 minutes to fully set.  I don't understand it, but they came out ok, just took a while...

Comment: @ircmaxell: If your water bath started cold, that's part of the thermal mass you need to heat, so the cupcakes aren't really that much "smaller" (because its the whole thing you're heating, cupcakes + water bath vs. springform pan + water bath). At least, that'd be my hypothesis.